# django accessing localhost from any machine connected to any network

Tags: python, django, networking, localhost

I have a django project that I am running on localhost:8000 and that works fine.
Now I want it to access from any machine that is connnected to other network.

Doing some google I found that I can do it by setting port forwarding from my router.
I have a tplink router and I did the following setting:

```
Service Port:27015
IP Address: my_ip_address   # obtained by ifconfig
Protocol: All
Status: Enabled
```

Now I run my project with `python manage.py my_ip_address:27015`

But when I run with `my_ip_address:27015` in url from another machine connected to another network I cannot view my site/page

Can anyone help me how to access my localhost outside the globe?

Comment: To which port do you forward it?

Comment: Service Port : 27015

Comment: But have you opened your firewall on your PC?

Comment: yeah my firewall is on

Comment: But have you `opened` the port `27015` on the firewall on your PC. If I understand correctly, your router is forwarding to the port, but your PC has not opened that port.

Comment: Here's what I did sudo ufw enable and sudo ufw allow 27015

Comment: Can you access the site from a machine on your local network (other than the server)?

Comment: yeah I can access the site from url '192.168.0.***:27015'.. It is running in my local machine.. I want to access the same site from another computer connected to another network

Comment: But, can you access it from another machine on your local network?

Comment: Then it's a router issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not access localhost form outside; localhost servers will only respond on the localhost "device".

you need to start the server, in this case django, and have it bind to your local address (192.168, or 10., etc).

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

will have it bind to all available IP addresses on your machine.

Then you can port forward on your router to your local machine (disable any firewall for that port on your local machine)

Comment: are you sure I cannot access from another network by port forwarding through router?

Comment: Yes. if you just do ```runserver``` it will bind to the localhost virtual device of the machine (which is local to just the machine, not the internal network that the router can see).

Comment: that means I cannot access my computer's ip address from another computer of another network right ? cuz if I can then I guess I could get what I want

Comment: your computers ip address should be something like 192.168.1.X or possibly some other "internal reserved" address. those can be accessed by your router, and if you port forward, the from the outside world using your public (ISP provided) ip address

Comment: so there is no way that I can access my site running in my machine to another machine connected in another network

Comment: @VishnuRaj Yes There Is! read my comments, run your django as i stated, and look on google how to port forward.  if this is a long term thing, you should look at running django through ngnix/apache as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did..

My configuration was correct.
To access from outside the world I just binded my isp ip address with my router port that I forwarded and to open I did

```
my_isp_ip_address:27015
```

and it work like a charm

Comment: I'm also trying to make my django project accessible from another computer over ip over another network. But I must have missed something. Can you explain in detail how you solved the problem? How did you set port forwarding from your router?