# Calling local api on a server from a hosted website

Tags: python, django, rest, web, network-programming

I'm currently hosting a website and I'm trying to call an API on a remote server. This remote server has a website running locally, and I'm trying to call a certain API from my website to the remote server's localhost. Is something like this possible, or would I have to host the website on the remote server so it isn't locally hosted.

For instance, would something like http://IP_address_of_server_goes_here:8000/get_matching_data/?XXXX be possible to get some data from this localhost?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer that is running a server with an API locally, you can only access it with the same computer and other computers on the same network. You have a few options:

**Connecting on the same wifi**

IF your client (connecting) device is on the same wireless network as the server, you can often access the server by using `http://12.0.0.1:8000/whatever`. There are plenty of resources for learning how to do this as it *can* be a tricky process. It looks like it may be slightly different for Django, check out this question: [django accessing localhost from any machine connected to any network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962547/django-accessing-localhost-from-any-machine-connected-to-any-network)

**Connecting from anywhere with localhost tunneling**

If you would like to connect to your server to test without being restricted by the localhost, you can take a look at providers such as [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) or [pagekite](http://pagekite.net). Essentially, localhost tunneling is *miniature* hosting. These providers give you limited access to using their subdomains for remote testing. DO NOT use this as a production solution, as they are not secure or very stable.

**Host it**

Check out [heroku](http://heroku.com) for free, easy hosting.

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer with the green arrow!  :)